# Clarification on opinion-based question that was closed

Tags: discussion

One of [my questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/127287/how-much-does-it-cost-to-raise-a-child-for-the-average-american-family) was closed for being "opinion-based". In the help center, it says that answers to opinion-based questions don't fit the format of the community because answers "will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise."

As it's titled, "How much does it cost to raise a child for the average American family?" can be answered with an empirical number.

I believe I answered the question with a wealth of objective data, drawn from a US government body, which I cited and linked in the post.  The sample for the study consisted of 30,000+ households and was weighted to reflect the U.S. population of interest by using BLS weighting methods.

Could anyone provide clarification on what part of this question is opinion-based and how I might be able to edit it so it better fits community guidelines? Thank you :)

Comment: It feels on-topic to me and a good question/answer pair, but let's see if any of the people who closed it want to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I thought it was on-topic and a nice "canonical" question/answer pair that could be used to clean up some other more specialised questions. But I wouldn't necessarily have overridden the community unilaterally if the majority felt it was off-topic and could explain why.

In the end it's also been reopened by the community so I think we can leave things there for now.